# Fast way to convert type between char* to custom union

Tags: c++

I have two types and one function.
One type is

```
char one[32]
```

The other type is

```
typedef union _DATA{
    UINT8 byte[32];
    INT8  iByte[32];
}DATA
```

The function gets DATA as input parameter,

`void Compute(DATA data){}`

Now, I have a `char*` (char[32]) type and I wish to convert it to `DATA` type and pass it as a parameter for `Compute`. Both types are 32Byte size, and I want a fast way to convert type.

I thought of `memcpy`,but it is slow since it copies the data.

Can I use pointer somehow to pass it char* as DATA type?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't use leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter, such symbol names are [reserved by the "implementation" (compiler ad standard library) in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/440558). Also, in C++ you don't need `typedef` for structures, classes or enumeration, a structure, class or enumeration tag can also be used as a type.

Comment: DATA d = * ((DATA *)one);

Comment: @Colin__s : theoretically, that's UB. On most architectures, it'll just work (tm).

Comment: What is the real usage of the union here? I believe that there is a underlying general design problem.

Comment: @Colin__s Thanks! I Think this might work

Comment: @Klaus yes.. I agree.. I don't know why union is there.. but the code is not mine and this is unchangeable so..

Comment: Just be aware as lorro said, it is undefined behavior. All depends on where the char array is, and whether you can do unaligned reads.

Comment: If you worry so much about copying, why is the union passed *by value* to the function? That will copy the data anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right. But the function is not made by me, and I wish to minimize the copy before passing it to function. Otherwise there are two copies so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of doing it without breaking strict aliasing and being well-defined is to copy from the character array into the correct array of the union.

Perhaps something like

```
DATA data;
if (std::is_signed<char>::value)
{
    std::copy_n(one, 32, data.iByte);
}
else
{
    std::copy_n(one, 32, data.byte);
}
```

And no it's not going to be "slow", unless you do this thousands of time per second. Measure and profile first, don't fall into the trap of premature optimization.